# How to add group and range to more like this component?

Tags: solr, search-engine, morelikethis

This is my requestHandler with mlt component inside it:

```
<requestHandler name="/standardmlt" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">      
     <int name="rows">1</int>          
     <str name="df">id</str>
     <str name="mlt">true</str>
     <int name="mlt.count">5</int>                 
     <str name="mlt.fl">id ,content</str>    
     <int name="mlt.mintf">2</int>
     <int name="mlt.mindf">1</int>
     <int name="mlt.minwl">3</int>
     <int name="mlt.maxwl">1000</int>
     <int name="mlt.maxqt">50</int>   
     <int name="mlt.maxntp">5000</int>    
     <bool name="mlt.boost">true</bool>  
     <str name="mlt.qf">id , content</str>
     <str name="mlt.interestingTerms">details</str>     
</lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

when I search for (for example) "http://www.apple.com/" in more like this result, it shows me :

```
 "moreLikeThis":{
    "http://www.apple.com/":{"numFound":370138,"start":0,"docs":[...
```

So I was wondering is there any way to have the result of more like this in ranges, for example 0-5 and 5-10 and ...? or how to set this "start:0" for mlt?

And the other question is that I know we can have grouping for our search, can we have it for mlt as well?